# How to set proxy_http_version in LUA code before upstreaming the request in nginx

Tags: nginx, lua, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location, openresty

I want to change the proxy http version in Lua code programmatically. Is there any way?

Yes, I know that we can set it via the **nginx config** file in the location/server block. Is there any way that I can do it using Lua dynamically per request?

Comment: With the ```os``` functions or better with ```io.popen``` cause it can return the result in a Lua variable.

Comment: I didn’t get you. Could you please elaborate? I want to do it in Lua Nginx.

Comment: I dont know Nginx. Never used. You tagged only: [lua]

Comment: Sorry my bad. I will edit it. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated 14.10.2020**

```
location / {
   content_by_lua_block {
       -- some logic here
       if flag then
          return ngx.exec("@http1_0")
       end
       return ngx.exec("@http1_1")
   }
}

location @http1_0 {
   proxy_pass ...;
   proxy_http_version 1.0;
   ...
}

location @http1_1 {
   proxy_pass ...;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   ...
}
```

Comment: But Proxy_http_version is not a header right? It’s a version of a protocol of a request. Can I change it by setting that as an header?

Comment: @SANDEEPMACHIRAJU you are correct, I will update my answer with alternative approach

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is content_by_lua_block should be the first life cycle function? Currently, my config file has "rewrite_by_lua_block", "access_by_lua_block", "header_filter_by_lua_block", "body_filter_by_lua_block" and "log_by_lua_block". 

I tested it but its not working. Can you help me out?

Comment: (or) Is there any way that we can acheive without content_by_lua_block? With pure nginx configuration itself?

Comment: I found the answer. Both proxy_pass and content_by_lua block cannot be in a single location block. In my case, I have it like that. so that's why it didn't worked for me. 

https://github.com/Kong/kong/issues/4000#issuecomment-440582143

Comment: yes, content_by_lua_block and proxy_pass both content phase directives, only one allowed. ngx.exec() you may call in rewrite and access phases.