# How to set proxy_http_version dynamically in LUA code before upstreaming the request in nginx

Tags: nginx, lua, nginx-location, kong, openresty

I followed the way suggested in [this StackOverflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64301671/how-to-set-proxy-http-version-in-lua-code-before-upstreaming-the-request-in-ngin/64331014?noredirect=1#comment113820780_64331014)

```
location / {
   content_by_lua_block {
      -- some logic here
      if flag then
         return ngx.exec("@http1_0")
      end
      return ngx.exec("@http1_1")
   }
}

location @http1_0 {
   proxy_pass ...;
   proxy_http_version 1.0;
   ...
}

location @http1_1 {
   proxy_pass ...;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   ...
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

> ```
> kong_1 | 2020/11/10 17:19:33 [error] 25#0: 37490 failed to run balancer_by_lua: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:576: attempt to index local 'balancer_data' (a nil value)
> kong_1 | stack traceback:
> kong_1 |  /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:576: in function 'balancer'
> ```

I want to change the proxy http version in Lua code programmatically. Is there any way?

Comment: From the log it seems you are using kong? If so, consider adding the `kong` tag :D

Comment: Sure i will add Kong tag @DarkWiiPlayer

Comment: @ShanmugapriyaNachimuthu, obviously you don't provide enough context. Your nginx conf snippet doesn't have balancer_by_lua. Without it we may only gues what is wrong with your balancer code.

Comment: @AlexanderAltshuler here is my full nginx.conf file https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y9PFbO9-cn_vPYDx2F7pNmzIUZHu1z5eFuN9q-LsOrM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @ShanmugapriyaNachimuthu, please, edit your post, no benefit for the community if we would lose context.

Comment: @AlexanderAltshuler I am getting the following error while posting my conf in post itself. That is why shared separately.  "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."